# Dynamic initialisation of array name in java?

Tags: java, linked-list, biginteger

I want to initialise a lot of arrays.The name of the array follows a sequence like array12,array13,array14,......array19,array22,array23...........array99.
Actually I have an array1 which contains some integer,an array two which contains some integer and I wan the common integers in both to array12.(similarly array2,3,4..9)
What is the best way to do it.
LinkList,Mapping,vector??
Keeping in mind my program used the subset(eg array12)very frequently.

I thought the best way is to store in array because I dont have to travel the linklist(or any other ways) the whole time.
But I cant write

```
    public int array12=new int[10];
    public int array13=new int[10];
```

morever while in the middle of code when my i(some integer)=1 and j=2 I want to access array12.
so how can i do it?..

I am actually tring to solve this problem.[question page](https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problems.php?pid=141185906040057&round=402976459784646)
Please give me answers related to my asked question not the answer to the fb question.
I want to do it myself.

Comment: I see a design issue over there.

Comment: definitly not vector. those old datastructures are synchronized by default and so slower than newer collections classes

Answer (score 2):

You need to go into arrays of higher dimensions - specifically, it appears that you are looking for a 3D array. The two integers in your design that go into the name (i.e. `1` and `2` in `array12`) should be the first two indexes of your 3D array.

```
int[][][] array = new int[10][][];
for (int i = 0; i != 10 ; i++) {
    array[i] = new int[10][];
    for (int j = 0 ; j != 10 ; j++) {
        array[i][j] = new int[10];
    }
}
```

Now accessing what has been `array34[i]` of your design would look like `array[3][4][i]`.

Comment: thanks,thats what I thought of.But still I will be needing around 50 3d  arrays.So i have to declare all that.And what aout accessing them in runtime?How am i going to access array12(if i=1 and j=2)

Comment: @Atul That's the thing, you don't need fifty, you need just one 3-D array. Inside it there would be 100 1-D arrays, each one addressable with two integer indexes. To access `array12`, you would write simply `array[1][2]`. So if you were looking for the fifth element of `array12`, i.e. `array12[5]`, yo would write `array[1][2][5]` now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a map - you cannot (easily) dynamically name things:

```
public final Map<Stiring, Integer[]> myMap = new HashMap<>(){
  {
    put("array1", new Integer[10]);
    put("array2", new Integer[10]);
    put("array3", new Integer[10]);
    ...more arrays
  }
};
```

You can use the anonymous class with instance intializer trick to put those arrays into your map, as above.

You can then reference the arrays using `Map.get`

```
final Integer[] myArray = myMap.get("array1");
```

**EDIT**

As per comment by @twain249 you can use a loop to populate your map:

```
public final Map<Stiring, Integer[]> myMap = new HashMap<>(){
  {
    for(int i=0;i<someNumber;++i) {
      for(int j=0;j<someOtherNumber;++j) {
        put("array" + i + "" + j, new Integer[10]);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: if they follow a pattern you can probably make do with a loop and set the name based on the index in the loop.

Comment: will this be coorect then?
        for(i=1;i<10;i++){
 for(j=1;j<10;j++){
  if(i<j){
   put("array"+String.valueOf(i)+String.valueOf(j),new Integer[10])
  }
 }
}

Comment: If you want numbers from 1 to 10 then you need `i<=10`, otherwise good.

Comment: thanks.I think its the best way to solve this qustion.Can I declare multi dimensional or 3d array using this?? new Integer[10][10]??

Comment: you can put whatever would be most useful into the `Map` just change the type of the value, for example `Map<String, Integer[][]>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. My approach for that would be to create and ArrayList and each array you want to create dynamically you simply add to the correct place in the ArrayList.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
ArrayList<int[]> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<int[]>(); // Creates a list of arrays.

int[] someArrayFromListOfArrays = listOfArrays.get(index); // Gets an array from arraylist

listOfArrays.add(new int[]); // Adds a new array to the collection

listOfArrays.add(index, new int[]); // This will insert an array into a specified location in the list
```

This should meet your needs.

Here is a spec of [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Hope it helps